# UIScrollView with subview of coreplot graph doesnot zoom frequently

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, core-plot

I have a scrollview with sub-view of core-plot graph view. It does not zoom frequently. If we are zooming the scrollview after scrolling the view, it will get zoom.

Every time the delegate method - `(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` will get called, but chance of calling the delegate method - `(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` is very less.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

```
[consumptionGraphView_ addSubview:graphPlottedView_];
[graphPlottedView_ setContentScaleFactor:consumptionGraphView_.contentScaleFactor];

consumptionGraphView_.contentSize = consumptionGraphView_.frame.size;
consumptionGraphView_.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
consumptionGraphView_.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
consumptionGraphView_.zoomScale = 0.1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was due to the presence of UIGestureRecognizers in GraphHostingView of CorePlot.

```
 for (UIGestureRecognizer * recognizer in hostingView.gestureRecognizers) {
        [hostingView removeGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    }
```

This code will remove the UIGestureRecognizers and the graph zooming is perfect now.

Comment: Set `allowPinchScaling` = NO on the hosting view to accomplish this automatically.